# C# excel chart text box - Use textbox index number to pass cell reference to Dynamically change text value

Tags: c#, excel, textbox

I have a text box referenced a cell thereby displaying the cell value as the text in the text box.
Problem: the text does not change as the cell value changes.

i think i can get the text box to change value in tandem with the reference cell IF I can assign the cell value to the **textbox index number**.

Can anyone help me get control over the textbox by using the index number and then assigning the cell reference to the textbox. I'll greatly appreciate any helpful inputs

Here is the code snippet:

```
Excel.Range donData1 = wsDashBoard.get_Range("C6", "C9");
donData1.Interior.Color = Color.White;
Excel.ChartObjects xlDonCharts1 = (Excel.ChartObjects)wsDashBoard.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject dbDonChart1 = (Excel.ChartObject)xlDonCharts1.Add(2, 8, 170, 170);
Excel.Chart chartDon1 = dbDonChart1.Chart;
chartDon1.SetSourceData(donData1);
chartDon1.ChartArea.Border.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Transparent);
chartDon1.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlDoughnut;
chartDon1.ChartStyle = 251;
chartDon1.HasTitle = false;
chartDon1.HasLegend = false;
Excel.Shape textBox1 = wsDashBoard.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 53, 72, 69, 37);                
Excel.Range donLab1 = wsDashBoard.get_Range("C3");
textBox1.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = donLab1.Value.ToString("0%");
```

Comment: You can set the textbox's `Formula` property to (eg) `=C3` and the content will change dynamically when C3 changes.

Comment: `textBox1.Formula = "=C3"`

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have tried this already but then the textbox displays =C3 as the text and not the cell value. Only way i could get the textbox to display cell value is as above in the code snippet (defining a range and then calling this range as the text assignment for the text box......the last line in the snippet above)

Comment: Sorry I posted before testing.  Try `textBox1.DrawingObject.Formula`  In VBA that works as expected: should carry over to C#.

Comment: Thanks Tim works like a charm. this is really great help ...considering the amount of time i spent looking for this simple line of code